# i want to open new window browser at every click event... in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, browser

I am just facing the issue at open new browser at **"each click event previous opened stay that"**. i want that.

Look i want to open window browser at click event... it opens fine.

But i want at each click it opens new browser. how can i do that?

it always override that new window. i want always open a new window.

i used:

```
function Validation(){
    var i=0;    
    if(document.netsim.emulatorNo.value=="")
    {
        alert ( "Please Fiil Emulator Number" );    
        netsim.emulatorNo.focus();      
        i=1;
    }else {
        var emu =  document.netsim.emulatorNo.value;
        var serverUrl = document.netsim.Apply.value;
        window.open('http://localhost:8080/SMSSimulator/NewEmulator.jsp?emulator='+emu+'&ServerUrl='+serverUrl,'mywindow','width=400,height=350');
    }
    if(i==1)
        return false;   
}
```

suggest me to find out my answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok i am trying to apply your answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open(url, unique_title, features)
```

If you want to open it always on the new window use a unique window title everytime, else it will keep on opening on the same window.

Example sample html and popup opens fine in new window always -

```
<html>
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function openWindow(){
        window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow'+counter,'width=400,height=350');
        counter++;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="button" id="button" onclick="openWindow()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added a simple html tested code. Appending integer would work fine as well

Answer (score 1):

you need to give different window names to each window. so, 'mywindow' needs to be changed. try something like;

```
var counter = 0;

function Validation(){ 
    var i=0;     
    if(document.netsim.emulatorNo.value=="") 
    { 
        alert ( "Please Fiil Emulator Number" );     
        netsim.emulatorNo.focus();       
        i=1; 
    }else { 
        var emu =  document.netsim.emulatorNo.value; 
        var serverUrl = document.netsim.Apply.value; 
        window.open('http://localhost:8080/SMSSimulator/NewEmulator.jsp?emulator='+emu+'&ServerUrl='+serverUrl,'mywindow'+counter,'width=400,height=350'); 
        counter++;
    } 
    if(i==1) 
        return false;    
}
```

Comment: maybe it refreshes at each click and counter resets. then try to use Math.random() instead of counter like 'mywindow'+Math.random()

Answer (score 1):

Here you open the new window in a specific place called 'mywindow'

```
window.open('http://localhost:8080/SMSSimulator/NewEmulator.jsp?emulator='+emu+'&ServerUrl='+serverUrl,'mywindow','width=400,height=350');
```

you can change it to blank or "_blank" and it will open it in a new window:

```
window.open('http://localhost:8080/SMSSimulator/NewEmulator.jsp?emulator='+emu+'&ServerUrl='+serverUrl,'','width=400,height=350');
```

there is no need to naming it unless you have a javascript that reference the window